# What is the proper design pattern to use when you have a bunch of extremely similar classes that can't share an interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an abstract class, called `Base` that handles a bunch of logic for handling some data I have. The API looks like this:

```
// Class has no abstract methods, but is uninstantiable
public abstract class Base {
    private Param param;

    protected Base() {}

    protected void setParam(Param param) {
        this.param = param
    }

    public void doThing() {
        // Code here to do a common thing
    }

    public void doOtherThing() {
        // Code here to do another common thing
    }

    protected void handle(Object... objects) {
        // This code delegates work to a scripting language via the param 
        // It is not type safe and the array of objects needed will vary depending 
        // on the implementing class.
    }
}
```

Of course, the weird thing here is the `handle(Objects...)` method. To show how it is used, look at one of the subclasses:

```
public class Person extends Base {
    protected Person(Param param) {
        super();
        setParam(param);
    }

    public void handle(String name, int age) {
        // Expose a type safe interface to the world
        super.handle(name, age);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the subclasses hide `super.handle`, which is protected, for certain arguments so that consumers of this class can have type safe interactions without passing around Arrays of objects. The problem is, I would like to create these from a factory that enforces having one instance of the subclass per param. Currently, this factory looks like this:

```
public class Factory {
    Map<Param, Person> persons;
    Map<Param, Other> others; // Other also extends Base

    public Person getPerson(Param param) {
        Person person = persons.get(param);

        if (person == null) {
            person = new Person(param);
            persons.put(param, person);
        }

        return person;
    }

    public Other getOther(Param param) {
        Other other = others.get(param);

        if (other == null) {
            other = new Other(param);
            other.put(param, other);
        }

        return other;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this sucks, but I can think of no better way to handle this case due the strange nature of interacting with a scripting language via the param, which relies on string construction to execute code. Does anyone have any guidance on how to clean up this design?

Comment: It's not obvious to me why this sucks. Perhaps because I'm only looking at one relatively simple example. Can you tell us more specifically what you wish was different?

Comment: Why not creating a factory method "public static Person getPerson(Param param)" inside the class Person, which also would keep a private static cache "Map<Param, Person> persons;"? Of course each subclass having a similar approach. I can understand this is not the best answer, but at least avoid you having to change the Factory class each time you have a new subclass...

Comment: It's difficult to recommend a specific change without more concrete statement of these interactions, but this might be a place where you want to consider using delegation instead of inheritance.

Comment: @JasonReid This sucks because the factory is complicated and confusing who first look at the code.

Comment: @robermann The reason I don't want to use static creators is that this factory allows me to mock out Base's subclasses in testing, and using static initializers would require a new test dependency (PowerMock). This isn't a strict requirement, but static initializers don't clear up the code enough to justify this in my opinion.

Comment: @DonRoby Yes, you are correct. Delegation would be much better, and that is another change I plan to make.

Comment: Why do you want only one `Person` per `Param`?

Comment: @tallseth Each subclass of `Base` maintains the state of all its interactions with its param object. If you could create two instances of the same `Base` subclass, each with the same `param`, you would reach an inconsistent state.

Comment: You could make the Base<P extends BaseParams> and make each param type its own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could generalize the factory class, with some generics and reflection for instantiating at runtime a specific subclass type:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Factory<T> {

    private Map<Param, T> instances = new HashMap<Param, T>();

    public final T create(Class<T> clazz, Param param) throws Exception {
        T cur = instances.get(param);

        if (cur == null) {
             cur = clazz.newInstance();
             ((Base)cur).setParam(param);
             instances.put(param, cur);
        }
        return cur;
    }
}
```

Subclasses should have the no-args constructor, not public; for consistency remove the with-param one:

```
public class Person extends Base {

    protected Person(){}

    public void handle(String name, int age) {
        // Expose a type safe interface to the world
        super.handle(name, age);
    }

}
```

An example of usage:

```
public class TestFactory {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Factory<Person> factory = new Factory<Person>();
        Person p = factory.create(Person.class, new Param());
    }
}
```

Of course I know this is not a pattern and it is not the more elegant code I could be proud of, but still avoid you having to change the factory for each new subclass, it does not use static methods and keeps in a single point the caching logic.

Comment: Everything is a patterns as soon as someone adopts it :) Also compare [Multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern#Java) that's roughly what you do.

Comment: Thank you zapl, never heard that pattern name!